# Git status is not working correctly

Tags: git, git-status

I don't think that my `git status` command is working correctly in this terminal session:

```
prompt> git add .

prompt> git status
On branch feature-api_sync
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

    modified:   api_sync/README.md
    modified:   storm_tier/README.md

prompt> git commit -m "updated instructions"
[feature-api_sync 4c55c55] updated instructions
 2 files changed, 6 insertions(+), 2 deletions(-)

prompt> git status
On branch feature-api_sync
nothing to commit, working directory clean # <== HOW DO I SEE THAT I MADE 1 COMMIT???
```

But how do I see this:

```
prompt> git status
On branch master
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 14 commits.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)

nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

Comment: Questions that don't "assume bugs" in other software usually fare better.

Comment: does the repository have a remote defined? If it has, then it will show that you have a new commit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wish to set tracking information for this branch you can do so with:

```
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/<branch> feature-model_in_ruby
```

Answer (score 3):

It's working completely correctly.  Do `git log` to see what happened in the past.

Comment: what git command can I use to show that I have 1 commit to push to the remote branch?

Comment: Do a `git fetch` (to get the remote history) and then `git log -1` and `git log -1 origin/master` . If the two logs are the same, there is nothing to commit.